# Proving that a quartic has exactly 2 real roots

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections

**Question:**

Find the equation of the normal to the hyperbola $xy=c^2$ at $P(ct,\frac{c}{t})$ then prove that *exactly* two normals can be drawn to the hyperbola $xy=c^2$ from a point $(0,k)$, where $k$ is real.

**Attempt**

I fount the equation of the normal. It is $ty-t^3x=c(1-t^4)$

Sub $x=0$ and $y=k$ to get: $ct^4+kt-c=0$

Now I need to prove that this equation has *exactly* 2 real roots.

How can I do that?

Comment: Blue, make that comment into an answer and get upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadn't someone already mentioned [Descartes' Rule of Signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)? Maybe I imagined it. Anyway ...

Take $k$ and $c$ non-zero (the zero cases are trivial), and name the polynomial $p(t)$.

- The coefficient sequence of $p(t)$ is $(c, k, −c)$, which has one sign change ($k$ matches sign with either $c$ or $−c$). Thus, by the Rule of Signs, $p$ has exactly one positive real root.
- The coefficient sequence for $p(−t)$ is $(c, −k, −c)$, which also has one sign change, so that $p$ has exactly one negative root.

Since zero isn't a root, and since we've run out of real candidates, the remaining roots must be non-real.

Comment: Thank you, yes I think you mentioned it but I deleted my last question as I didn't write the full question. The thing is that I don't think I can use this theorem in high school, unless I prove it properly.

Comment: @user2357: It wasn't me that brought-up the Rule of Signs in the previous version of the question. Be that as it may ... I learned the Rule of Signs in high school (Pre-Calculus). In any case, perhaps you should add some context about what level of approach you *can* use. Pre-Calculus polynomial lore, Calculus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(t)=ct^4+kt-c$$

At t=0 we have $$f(t)=-c$$

Also, $$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \pm \infty} = \infty $$ so by intermediate value theorem there exist at least 2 real roots; one positive, one negative.

Edit:

Now consider the derivative: $$f'(t) = 4ct^3+k$$

This is clearly strictly increasing, so there is only one turning point of f(t), hence exactly two roots.

Comment: But I need to prove that it has *exactly* two real roots.

Comment: Why is the derivative/function "clearly increasing"? Do we know whether $\,c,k\,$ are positive numbers?

Comment: Well, k will have no effect on inc/dec behaviour; if c<0 then the same argument still applies; but f(t) is now upside down and f' decreasing.

Comment: Why k has no effect? I think it does: $$f'(t)>0\;\forall\,\iff t^3>-\frac k{4c}\ldots$$

Comment: f' being monotonic is what is important here. k being a constant means that it will not cause the derivative to have any additional turning points. Because f' has only one root (and no value of k can change this) then f has only one turning point. Noting that the only turning point is on the other side of the axis than the functions limits to plus/minus infinity means, by the IVT, that there are exactly two roots.

Comment: But $\,f'\,$ may *not* be monotonic (perhaps you meant $\,f\,$ ?), and for some values of $\,t\,$ it may be positive, and thus $\,f\,$ ascending, and for some other negative, and thus $\,f\,$ descending. Indeed, from here we already see there's only one *real* root for $\,f'\,$ and your argument would follow taking care of of the max/min. value obtained, since $\;f\to sign(c)\cdot\infty\;$ both when $\,t\to\infty\,,\,t\to -\infty\,$

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

Let the roots of $ct^4+kt-c$ be $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$

$\sum \alpha =-\frac{0}{c}=0$

$\sum \alpha \beta =\frac{0}{c}=0$

$\sum \alpha ^{2}=\left ( \sum\alpha \right )^{2}-2\sum \alpha \beta =0-2(0)=0$

Therefore, there must be at least one imaginary root in $\alpha ^{2}+\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2}+\delta^{2}$ because it is impossible to get zero if all the roots are real. Since the coefficients are real, by the complex conjugate root theorem, there must be two imaginary roots.

To prove that not all the roots are imaginary, we can use FireGarden's answer.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is that first summation? What are those $\,\alpha\,,\,\beta\;$ ?

Comment: $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are the roots of $f(t)$

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing. Perhaps it'd be better (1) to explicitly write that those are the roots and (2) if you want to use summatories for the Newton formulae, call the roots $\,\alpha_i\;,\;i=1,2,3,4\;$

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that but I was taught to use this notation so using a different one may confuse the test markers.